# Почему дублируются новости при выводе постов через ajax wp?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

Создал страницу и накатил туда вывод определенных постов, добавил пагинацию + ajax. Вопрос, при клике на кнопку просто новости дублируются, подскажите что сделал не так?
А так же как сделать динамическую пагинацию? а то при показать еще, остается такой какой и был

Вывожу посты так

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type"        => "post",                  # post, page, custom_post_type
    "post_status"      => "publish",                       # статус записи
    "posts_per_page"   => 3,                               # кол-во постов вывода/загрузки
    "category_name"    => "news",  
    'orderby' => 'date',
)); ?>

<?php if ($posts->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
<a class="col-md-4" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="news-card">
<div class="thumbnail img__post" >
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="meta">
<div class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('d F Y'); ?></div>
<div class="view">
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="block">
              <h3 class="posts-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
         
      

<!--здесь выводится миниатюра записи-->

<?php the_content(); ?>
</div></a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php // AJAX загрузка постов
if ($posts->max_num_pages > 1) { ?>

    <script>
        var current_page = 1;
    </script>

    <button 
        type="button"
        class="btn--load"
        data-param-posts='<?= json_encode($posts->query_vars); ?>' 
        data-max-pages="<?= $posts->max_num_pages; ?>"
        data-tpl="portfolio"
    >
        Загрузить ещё
    </button>
<?php } ?>

<?php     post_pagination($paged, $posts->max_num_pages); 
?>

<?
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".btn--load").on("click", function () {
        const button = $(this);
        button.html("Загрузка...");

        const data = {
            "action": "load_more",
            "query": button.data("param-posts"),
            "page": current_page,
            "tpl": button.data("tpl")
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    button.html("Загрузить ещё");
                    button.prev().prev().after(data);
                    current_page++;
                    if (current_page == button.attr("data-max-pages")) {
                        button.remove();
                    }
                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

load-posts.php

```
<?php

add_action("wp_ajax_load_more", "load_posts");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more", "load_posts");
function load_posts()
{
    $args = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["query"]), true);
    $args["paged"] = $_POST["page"] + 1;

    $posts = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type"        => "post",
  "category_name"    => "news",  
));

    $html = '';

    if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();

?>


<a class="col-md-4" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="news-card">
<div class="thumbnail img__post" >
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="meta">
<div class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('d F Y'); ?></div>
<div class="view">
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
</div>
</div>
           <div class="block">
              <h3 class="posts-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
         
      

<!--здесь выводится миниатюра записи-->

<?php the_content(); ?>
</div></a>
<?

        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($html);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете новый экземпляр `WP_Query` в функции `load_posts()`, не передавая в него параметры запроса, что приводит к тому, что он отображает все записи из выбранной категории.

Вы используете стандартный цикл WP `if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();`, который не учитывает текущую страницу и поэтому выводит все записи каждый раз, когда происходит AJAX-загрузка

Что касаемо динамической пагинации, вам нужно добавить параметры `paged` и `posts_per_page` в `WP_Query` и передать их в AJAX-запрос, эти параметры должны быть вычислены на стороне сервера, а не на стороне клиента.

AJAX-обработчик:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', 'load_more');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', 'load_more');

function load_more() {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $postsPerPage = $_POST['posts_per_page'];

    $args = json_decode($query, true);
    $args['paged'] = $page;
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $postsPerPage;

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
        while ($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'post');
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#load-more').on('click', function() {
        var button = $(this),
            container = $('#posts-container'),
            currentPage = button.data('current-page'),
            maxPages = button.data('max-pages'),
            newPage = currentPage + 1,
            postsPerPage = button.data('posts-per-page'),
            ajaxUrl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data = {
                'action': 'load_more',
                'query': button.data('query'),
                'page': newPage,
                'posts_per_page': postsPerPage,
                'tpl': button.data('tpl')
            };

        button.addClass('loading').text('Загрузка...');

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(result) {
                button.removeClass('loading');

                if (result) {
                    container.append(result);

                    if (newPage == maxPages) {
                        button.remove();
                    } else {
                        button.data('current-page', newPage).text('Загрузить еще');
                    }
                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Темплейт:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$posts_per_page = 3;
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    "post_type"        => "post",
    "post_status"      => "publish",
    "posts_per_page"   => $posts_per_page,
    "category_name"    => "news",
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'paged'            => $paged,
)); ?>

<?php if ($posts->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div id="posts-container" class="row">
        <?php while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="news-card">
                    <div class="thumbnail img__post">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <div class="date"><?php echo get_the_date('d F Y'); ?></div>
                        <div class="view">
                            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <h3 class="posts-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ($posts->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button id="load-more" class="btn btn-primary" data-current-page="<?php echo $paged; ?>" data-max-pages="<?php echo $posts->max_num_pages; ?>" data-posts-per-page="<?php echo $posts_per_page; ?>">
                Загрузить еще
            </button>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Благодарю!!
Есть еще один вопрос, касательно js в общем как убрать кнопку если это последняя страница?
а то там на последнем из за того что в ряд 1 новость верстка едет

Comment: @reddyk я обновил код.  Кнопка не будет отображаться, если это последняя страница

Comment: не так описал проблему, если я через навигацию перейду к последней странице то кнопка Загрузить еще она остается, ну если она на нее нажимать до последней, то да нету ее

Comment: @reddyk в JS замените if (newPage == maxPages) на if (newPage >= maxPages)